# How to replace ASCII character using VBA

Tags: vba

I'm trying to replace ASCII character 164 (which is ñ) with character 110. Here's my code: Private Sub CB_Kontynuuj_Click()

```
'sprawdzanie czy podane słówko zgadza sie z tłumaczeniem w bazie
If Replace(pobierzTlumaczenieZBazySlowek(lblJezykZrodlowy.Caption), Asc(164), Asc(110)) = tbJezykDocelowy.Text Then

    'jeśli tak, to zaliczamy słówko na plus
    Call zaliczJako(lblJezykZrodlowy.Caption, DOBRZE)

Else

    'jeśli nie, to zaliczamy słówko na minus
    Call zaliczJako(lblJezykZrodlowy.Caption, ZLE)

End If

zmienCzcionkeNaCzarna

'od razu pbieramy kolejne słówko
pobierzKolejneSlowko
```

End Sub

I don't get an error but it doesn't work.

Comment: Note: In addition to `ChrW` there is also `AscW`—in case you were to ever actually need it. (Also, ñ is not in the ASCII character set; and, Asc and Chr don't necessarily work with ASCII, anyway—In fact, I don't think VBA itself can ever use ASCII. [Strings are sequences of UTF-16 code units, just like in Java, JavaScript, VB4-6, .NET, ….])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem is that you are using `Asc()` function, which returns integer value, based on first character (digit in this case):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/asc-function

You should use `ChrW()` function instead:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/chr-function

You can create a loop which will populate worksheet with characters returned by this function and then find the one needed.

Try `ChrW(241)` instead of `Asc(164)` and `ChrW(110)` instead of `Asc(110)`.